# Add aliases to .sh files

Tags: bash, shell

For some reason, I had to add an alias to my bash. I have added the alias in `/root/.bashrc` which also contains the following piece of code:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

The new alias works like a charm when it is used in the console. However, when I execute a script file `myscript.sh` with this alias in, I get a `command not found` error. It seems like I should tell `.sh` files to use the same environment as `bash` but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The solution here is to remove the problem. Aliasing Bash is not a good idea.

Comment: Note that you are only setting the alias for `root`. And `root` really has no business using aliases in scripts. You haven't given enough information to be sure, but it sounds like you are setting yourself up for a fall. I would strongly urge you not to use aliases in shell scripts that are run by root.

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are not inherited by sub-processes.  If you *want* the alias in your script, you *could* source in your /root/.bashrc again.. but, I wouldn't do that.  I prefer to be more verbose in my scripts and use the actual command name.

I see aliases as being more of a keystroke saver in the shell.  That isn't really necessary in a script.  If anything, using the actual command, adds better understanding for anyone who may need to maintain your script later.